# How to register Android device on GCM

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

Developing Android app using Ionic framework, I have created one new project and generated API in Google Cloud Platform.

Now I need to register my device in GCM to get device registration ID. Please let me know the proper steps to get the registration id.